# Complexification and a canonical isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. How to build a canonical isomorphism $(W^{*})_{\mathbb{C}} \cong (W_{\mathbb{C}})^{*}$, where by $W_{\mathbb{C}}$ we denote a $W$ complexification.

Would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 2):

$(W_{\mathbb{C}})^{*} = Hom_{\mathbb{C}} (W_{\mathbb{C}},\mathbb{C}) = Hom_{\mathbb{C}} (W \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C},\mathbb{C}) \simeq Bil_{\mathbb{R}}(W,\mathbb{C};\mathbb{C})$ by the universal property of $\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}$. What can you say now about $(W^{*})_{\mathbb{C}} = Hom_{\mathbb{R}} (W,\mathbb{R})\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ knowing its universal property ?

See Bourbaki, Algèbre, Chapitre 2, paragraph 5, section 4 for details.